# Laravel if statement on blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to filter out my users table data based on roles and split it into 2 table on the view.

**My Roles:**

1. admin
2. entry
3. junior
4. senior

The one table i want it to show only data of users with admin role and the other table should show data of users with entry, junior roles.

**Table 1 works perfectly:**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   @if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == 'admin')
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
         <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
         <td>{{ implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) }}</td>
         <td class="row" style="margin-left: 1%">
           <a href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', $user->id) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</a>
           <form action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user) }}" method="POST">
               @csrf
               {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
           </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

**Table 2 is the one that is giving me issues:**

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   @if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == ['entry' && 'junior'])
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">{{$user->id}}</th>
         <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
         <td>{{ implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) }}</td>
         <td class="row" style="margin-left: 1%">
           <a href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', $user->id) }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right:10px;">Edit</a>
           <form action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user) }}" method="POST">
               @csrf
               {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
           </form>
        </td>
     </tr>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

**I have tried following:**

```
@if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == ['entry', 'junior'])
```

```
@if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == 'entry' && 'junior')
```

```
@if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == 'entry', 'junior')
```

```
@if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == ('entry' 'junior'))
```

```
@if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == ('entry', 'junior'))
```

**and this one:**

```
@if(implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) == 'entry' || 'junior')
```

**Returns a table with all the data.**

I need the table to return all the data with user roles of entry and junior.

And i can't use the NOT EQUAL to cause there's a senior role that is catered for separately.

Comment: implode (', ',$user->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()  , first echo this check what exactly you are getting after imploding .

Comment: contains all the roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making it more complex than it needs to be. `$user->roles` is a collection, which means you have a lot of helper-functions at your disposal. All you need to do is check if the collection *contains* either value.

```
@if ($user->roles->whereIn('name', ['entry', 'junior'])->count())
```

You can also simplify your working `@if` with helper functions,

```
@if ($user->roles->contains('name', 'admin'))
```